# enumerating integer sets, ordered primary by sum and secondary by lexicographic order

Tags: combinatorics

I am trying to enumerate all integer-tuples of a given size $n$, i.e. all $A \in \{ a = (a_1, a_2, ... a_n) | a_i \in \mathbb{N}, 1 \le i \le n, a_1 < a_2 < ... < a_n \}$. Background is that each tuple should represent a set of integer values, i.e. set elements are listed in ascending order.

The enumeration should be ordered by the sum of the tuple elements ($s(A) = \sum_{i=1}^{n}a_i$). For two n-tuples having the same sum the tuple which comes lexicographically first should be first in the enumeration. So what I am actually looking for is an algorithm that determines the *next* tuple in the enumeration given the *current* tuple.

e.g. for $n=3$ the resulting output should be, starting with $A_0 = (1, 2, 3)$:

$A_0 = (1, 2, 3), \qquad s(A_2)=6$

$A_1 = (1, 2, 4), \qquad s(A_1)=7$

$A_2 = (1, 2, 5), \qquad s(A_2)=8$

$A_3 = (1, 3, 4), \qquad s(A_3)=8$

$A_4 = (1, 2, 6), \qquad s(A_3)=9$

$A_5 = (1, 3, 5), \qquad s(A_3)=9$

$A_6 = (2, 3, 4), \qquad s(A_3)=9$
$...$

So far, I came up with something that allows to enumerate all tuples, however not in monotonic sum-order, using this simple rule:

1. find the left-most tuple-element that can be incremented, i.e. the lowest index $i$ with $i < n$ and $a_i + 1 < a_n$. If no such index exists, set $i := n$
2. increment the tuple-element at position $i$ and "reset" all elements to the left. Elements at positions $>i$ are left unchanged:
   $next(A) = next((a1, a2, ..., a_{i-1}, a_i, a_{i+1} ..., a_n)) = (1, 2, ..., i-1, a_i+1, a_{i+1}, ..., a_n)$
   This rule generates the sequence $(1,2,3), (1,2,4), (1,3,4), (2,3,4), (1,2,5), (1, 3, 5),...$ with the corresponding sums $6, 7, 8, 9, 8, 9, ...$.

Does anyone have an idea on how to modify this approach to guarantee the monotonic-sum condition?
Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: It looks like a question belongs to Stack Overflow. It is easily answered with code.

Answer (score 0):

Decrement the right-most element that can be decremented; then increment the right-most element to its left that can be incremented. If this isn’t possible, you’re done with this sum; start the next sum with $a_i=i$ except $a_n$ chosen to complete the sum.

Comment: I'm not sure if this will always yield the next tuple for the same sum in lexicographic order. Consider the counter-example $(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 9, 10)$ with sum $34$. According to the given rule the next element would be $(1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 10)$ (with sum $34$) however the tuple $(1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 11)$ (also sum $34$) would be expected first.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an algorithm to find the lexicographically next tuple with a given sum.

Given an $n$-tuple, and a number $x$ in the tuple, let us say that $x$ is "incrementable" as long as these conditions hold:

- $x+1$ does not appear in the tuple.
- There exists a number $y$ in the tuple, such that $y\ge x+3$, and such that $y-1$ is not in the tuple.

Using this definition, here is how we find the next tuple.

1. Find the largest incrementable number in the tuple. Call this number $x$. Replace $x$ with $x+1$.
2. All of the numbers after $x$, except for the last number, should be replaced with the smallest number possible. This means that after $x+1$ will come $x+2,x+3,x+4,$ etc.
3. Finally, the last number is replaced with whatever number will preserve the sum.

For example, in the tuple $(1,2,3,4,5,9,10)$, the only incrementable number is $x=5$. This is fine because $6$ is not in the tuple, and because we can have $y=9$, with $8$ not appearing in the tuple, and $9\ge 5+3$. So, we replace $5$ with $6$. The next number, $9$, is replaced with the smallest number possible, so there is $7$ after $6$. Finally, the last number, $10$, is replaced with $11$ to maintain the sum. The result is $(1,2,3,4,6,7,11)$.